# communicate from parent to popup tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen a lot of posts on communicating from the popup back to parent using `window.opener.$('#myDiv')`. 
  
But once a popup is opened, how does the parent: target and control a div inside the popup?

I'm opening my popup using `window.open(url, 'myPopup', 'width=50', 'height=50');`

Comment: Is the parent and the target on the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adress the parent from the popup like this:

```
window.opener.foo();
```

or, on a generic way:

```
window.opener.property
```

And, to make sure the parent is still alive:

```
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
{
  // do something
}
```

On the parent view, you might try:

```
function add_content(page, text)
{
  var texts = page.document.getElementById("content");
  texts.innerHTML += text;
}

function start()
{
  var popup_page = window.open("popup.htm");
  var str = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  alert(str);
  add_content(popup_page, window.location+" : "+str);
  // window.close(); // ?
}
```

Comment: yes,  i know.  how do you go from parent to popup was the question

Comment: thank you for the help.  But im not understanding how you can target a div inside the popup once `add_content()` has been called.

Comment: In fact, you can access anything from the popup with its returning variable, popup_page. Ex: popup_page.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'someText';